# TypeScript: can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

Tags: typescript, express, npm, package.json

I've the following `index.ts`:

```
import { User } from "./datatypes"
import express from 'express';

 console.log("hello world")
```

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "simple_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc index.ts && node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.23",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  }
}
```

And this is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "target": "es6",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "lib": ["es2015"]
  }
```

When I write `npm run start`, I obtain:

```
 Module '"/mnt/c/Users/raffa/Desktop/simple_app/node_modules/@types/express/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

2 import express from 'express';
         ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts:133:1
    133 export = e;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: in package .json if I substitute "start": "tsc index.ts && node index.js" with     "start": "tsc -w && node index.js", it works, but in the terminal, I can't see anything (I can't see console.log("hello world")

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you call `tsc` from the command line with a specific file path, it will ignore your `tsconfig.json`

Typescript docs (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

> When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json files are ignored.

This means that the `esModuleInterop` part of tsconfig.json will have no effect if you call `tsc index.ts`.

It's possible to work around it by using `import * as express from 'express';`, but there may be other issues arising from ignored TS configs.

One problem with `tsc -w && node index.js` (from one of the comments) is that the `-w` will make it wait instead of terminating by itself, which means you won't get to the part after the "&&". 
 So, you won't get to the `node index.js` part.

(But at least this time, `tsc` doesn't get one specific file, therefore the config is not ignored)

Also, in your config, the `outDir` is set to `dist`, so the compiled file will go there. So, you should use the following instead:
`tsc && node ./dist/index.js`